# Search Input Is Cancelling Text as one types in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, search

I have an issue with search input box where, as I type in the search, the last typed text get cancelled.

```
 <input
      class="navbar-searchbar__text-field"
      type="search"
      :value="searchQuery"
      name="query"
      placeholder="Search"
      autocomplete="off"
      @keyup="collectSearchQuery($event.target.value)"
    />
```

This is the method

```
async collectSearchQuery(searchQuery) {
      this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
      await this.handleSearch(searchQuery);
      this.searchHidden = true;
    },
```

I don't know why that issue is happening. kindly help if you have any solution

Comment: What do you mean with "cancelling"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you assign the new value to this.searchQuery which is just one key instead of adding it to this.searchQuery string.